# Recursive method return numbers from int to 0

Tags: java, recursion, methods, command-line, return

I'm having trouble with a recursive method that will return and print in my main method the numbers from X (X being a int on commandline) to 0. Returning the numbers as a String.

For example my commandline argument is 4.
My output should be: 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

I kind of understand how to reverse a string like: "123" to "321".. But no clue when getting a integer like 3, and returning it like "3, 2, 1, 0" as a string. :o

My code atm:

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
      if (commandlineArguments.length == 0) {
         System.out.println("Please enter a least one commandline!");
      } 
      else {
         Integer number = new Integer(0); // initialize number
         try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(commandlineArguments[0]);
         } 
         catch (NumberFormatException exception) { // NumberFormatException
            System.out.println(exception + " is not a integer!");
            System.exit(1); // end program
         }
         String reverse = reverse1(number);
         System.out.println(reverse);
      }
   }

   public static String reverse1(Integer number){
      if (number == 0){
         return "";
      } 
      else{
         return "";
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Use [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)).

Comment: Why both the return statements are returning  empty string in your reverse1 method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static String reverse1(int number){
   if (number == 1){
      return "1";
   } else {
      return number + ", " + reverse1(number - 1);
   }
}
```

The trick with recursion is - in my opinion - always to search the trivial case.
So here the easiest input is 1 and the result would be "1"

```
reverse1(1) = "1";
```

And then you need that "strange" recursion step where you reduce your input towards that trivial case.

```
reverse1(n) = n, reverse(n-1)
```

Here you just say:

> The result of a number *n* is always the result of "this number minus 1" with that extra number *n* in front.

Think about it, its quite logical.

It's sometimes not easy to think of a problem in that "recursive way". But often it makes things alot easier.

Comment: Hmm, your answer is indeed correct! But, can you explain to me how reverse1(number - 1); works :). I mean, I really want to understand the concept :D

Comment: asdfghjk awesome explanation! A recursion is like a loop! And is ended by the base case. I understand now. Thank you so much Mikescher :D

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
    printNumber(number);

}

public static String printNumber(Integer number){
    if (number == 0){
       return "0";
    } 
    return number +" " + printNumber(number-1);
}
```